# segmentation fault found in code snippet 1 but not code snippet 2 while both are implemented in similar manner

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am getting segmentation fault in below code 1 at line- Line1. the same code is written using malloc function in code snippet 2, but no such error is found in code 2.
Can you please let me know the possible reasons behind it.

I know that i am trying to access a memory location in code1 which is not initialized- this could be the reason for seg'n fault but my question is, if this is true, then why is no error observed in code2.

Thanks!

code snippet 1:

```
    struct tnode
    {
        int d;
        struct tnode *left;
        struct tnode *right;
    };

    void printLOT(struct tnode *n)

    {
    tnode *q[20];
    int front=0, rear=-1;

    if(n==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"no element in tree.";
        return;
    }

    struct tnode *tmp=n;
    while(tmp)
    {
        cout<<tmp->d<<" ";  //*Line1*
        if(tmp->left!=NULL)
        {
            q[++rear]=tmp->left;
        }
        if(tmp->right!=NULL)
        {
            q[++rear]=tmp->right;
        }
        tmp=q[front++];

    }
    return;
}
```

code snippet 2:

```
void printLevelOrder(struct node* root)
{
    int rear, front;
    struct node **queue = createQueue(&front, &rear);
    struct node *temp_node = root;

    while (temp_node)
    {
        printf("%d ", temp_node->data);

        /*Enqueue left child */
        if (temp_node->left)
            enQueue(queue, &rear, temp_node->left);

        /*Enqueue right child */
        if (temp_node->right)
            enQueue(queue, &rear, temp_node->right);

        /*Dequeue node and make it temp_node*/
        temp_node = deQueue(queue, &front);
    }
}

/*UTILITY FUNCTIONS*/
struct node** createQueue(int *front, int *rear)
{
    struct node **queue =
        (struct node **)malloc(sizeof(struct node*)*MAX_Q_SIZE);

    *front = *rear = 0;
    return queue;
}

void enQueue(struct node **queue, int *rear, struct node *new_node)
{
    queue[*rear] = new_node;
    (*rear)++;
}

struct node *deQueue(struct node **queue, int *front)
{
    (*front)++;
    return queue[*front - 1];
}
```

Comment: *Undefined behavior* does not guarantee a segfault.

Comment: `cout<<tmp->d<<" ";  //*Line1*` does not compile.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that i am trying to access a memory location in code1 which is not initialized- this could be the reason for seg'n fault but my question is, if this is true, then why is no error observed in code2.

Because reading uninitialized memory has undefined behaviour.